# Fluent automappings override single property

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I'm using Fluent Nhibernate with AutoMappings. It provides ability to override any mapped property in following way:

```
public class CommunityMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Community>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Community> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.Description).Length(5000);
        mapping.Cache.ReadWrite();
    }
}
```

This class changes not only `Length` property of `Description` column, but also it changes column name in mappings. The same goes to `HasMany` and others. For example I want to disable lazy loading for particular collection, but leave all other attributes as set by automappings. Is it possible with FNH?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

```
public class ContractMappingOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<Contract>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Contract> mapping)
    {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Details).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

I just copied that from my production code.

Comment: Here you change all properties of has many association. I want to change ONLY lazy loading, but do not change all others.